# WMT14 loading dataset code worked last week, but now it does not

Tags: tensorflow

I'm just trying to download the wmt14 dataset to replicate the results from the Attention is All You Need paper.  This code worked last week, but now when I try to run it I get this warning until it gets an Error.  Any ideas why?

Warning:
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=9, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)'))': /wmt13/training-parallel-europarl-v7.tgz

Error:
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, body, headers, retries, timeout, chunked, response_conn, preload_content, decode_content, enforce_content_length)
467             try:
--> 468                 self._validate_conn(conn)
469             except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

54 frames
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.statmt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wmt13/training-parallel-europarl-v7.tgz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
515             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
516                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 517                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
518
519             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.statmt.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wmt13/training-parallel-europarl-v7.tgz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1007)')))

Code:
# Load the French-English dataset
examples, metadata = tfds.load('wmt14_translate/fr-en', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
train_examples, val_examples = examples['train'], examples['validation']

```
# Define the tokenizer for English using the subword tokenizers from TFDS
tokenizer_en = tfds.deprecated.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
    (en.numpy() for en, fr in train_examples), target_vocab_size=2**13)

# Define the tokenizer for German using the subword tokenizers from TFDS
tokenizer_fr = tfds.deprecated.text.SubwordTextEncoder.build_from_corpus(
    (fr.numpy() for en, fr in train_examples), target_vocab_size=2**13)
```

I tried restarting runtime, new notebooks, and some other stuff and nothing I've tried worked so far.  Seems like part of my problem is its looking for wmt13 instead of wmt14, but I don't think I caused that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it happened to me as well. Statml website ssl expired. I reloaded my colab midnight and cannot resume experiment...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).